# How to show database tables if it is hidden in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

In my remote server some system configuration problem system harddisk was changed.So in SQL Server all data was deleted, used xx database which has no tables but using query (select * from information.schema.tables) it displaying base tables only.How to show them?

[image: SSMS]

Comment: You say, "all data was deleted". This would imply that you aren't going to find any tables, as they count as 'data', and have therefore been... deleted.

Comment: Also, your screenshot (which is linked in a rather odd way), shows you are trying to run your query in the master database (the drop-down in the top left), not in the database you have highlighted in the object explorer.

Comment: @EdB: that's normal with SSMS. When you pick "SELECT top 200 rows" from the context menu, it always runs the query against the master database. I have no idea why.

Comment: What does it mean "show tables in before"? I see your tables there. You can get data from them. What's missing, exactly?

Comment: @siride - yes you are correct. The 'select top 200 rows' query will fully qualify the database and schema, but then if the OP attempts to run a query in that window *without* specifying the database, it will run in the master database. One would sincerely hope that there aren't any user tables in the master database!